# What is [Makefile] and " end_of_line " in editorconfig?

Tags: editorconfig

What is `[Makefile]` in `.editconfig` file? It's not explained well in any of the websites. Can anyone explain about it? Also what do the values of `" end_of_line "` in editorconfig mean? The values are mentioned as `lf`, `cr`, or `crlf` but what does that describe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entries in square brackets (`[]`) are patterns of files the following rules should apply to. `[Makefile]` is a simple pattern with no wildcards that matches the name "Makefile" exactly. It refers to common [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)s.

The `end_of_line` entry refers to the character(s) that is used to signify an end of a line.

- LF stands for [Line Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\n`)
- CR stands for [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`\r`)
- CRLF is simply CR followed by LF (i.e., `\r\n`)

Comment: That helped. Thank you